# How does the <div> tag support HTML code?

Tags: html, google-chrome, attributes, code-snippets, divide

I have been searching on Google and other search engine products and searching:

> What is `<div>` used for in HTML?

Here is what I get:

> The `<div>` tag defines a division or a section in an HTML document. The `<div>` tag is used as a container for HTML elements - which is then styled with CSS or manipulated with JavaScript. The `<div>` tag is easily styled by using the class or id attribute. Any sort of content can be put inside the `<div>` tag!

Is this true? I want to hear from the professionals. How are you to divide content inside HTML? the "body" attribute is another question I have, but I am only allowed to ask one question at a time.

Look at my code I have, and `<div>` I see isn't helping, at all:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<h1> Example Title </h1>
<p> Example Paragraph referring to the Example Title.</p>
<div id="div"/>
<progress onload="https://google.com"></progress>
</div>
```

How is `<div>` helping with the `<progress>` attribute? How does `<div>` help with anything, really?

Comment: `div` is a container. Whether you need a container depends on a lot of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, into the div-tag you can put anything you want.

since we all want clean and easy readable code, it's better to have tags with a special meaning, thats why there is something called: semantic html.

> What are Semantic Elements?
> A semantic element clearly describes its meaning to both the browser and the developer.

there is nothing wrong at using div-tags as much as you want. but in future you, or you developer-teammates will have problems to read and understand your code.

as Heretic Monkey said in the comment:
the div is a container. for example:

```
<div class="any-class">
  <article>
    <h2>Google Chrome</h2>
    <p>Google Chrome is a web browser developed by Google, released in 2008. Chrome is the world's most popular web browser today!</p
  </article>
  <article>
    <h2>Mozilla Firefox</h2>
    <p>Mozilla Firefox is an open-source web browser developed by Mozilla. Firefox has been the second most popular web browser since January, 2018.</p>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h2>Microsoft Edge</h2>
    <p>Microsoft Edge is a web browser developed by Microsoft, released in 2015. Microsoft Edge replaced Internet Explorer.</p>
  </article>
</div>
```

width the div with class .any-class, you can for example style the whole content or use javascript on it or...

try to avoid overusing div-tags like the following:

```
<div class="any-class">
  <div>
    <h2>Google Chrome</h2>
    <p>Google Chrome is a web browser developed by Google, released in 2008. Chrome is the world's most popular web browser today!</p
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>Mozilla Firefox</h2>
    <p>Mozilla Firefox is an open-source web browser developed by Mozilla. Firefox has been the second most popular web browser since January, 2018.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>Microsoft Edge</h2>
    <p>Microsoft Edge is a web browser developed by Microsoft, released in 2015. Microsoft Edge replaced Internet Explorer.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is a small "tutorial" about semantic-html
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp

Answer (score 0):

Div tags are good if you want to do css to one or more elements. Some good examples of them in action would be if you looked at the bootstrap documentation since to use a lot of that framework you need to use divs to reference classes.